# Cannot get inner join to execute with desired output

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join

```
JOIN payment p2
    ON p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id
    AND p1.payment_date = p2.payment_date + INTERVAL '1 month'
JOIN customer c
    ON p1.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq8ou.png)

I am attempting to answer the following:

> Find the difference across their monthly payments during 2007. Write a query to compare the payment amounts in each successive month. Repeat this for each of these 10 paying customers.

Currently my query will output empty tables.

I tried:

```
JOIN payment p2 
ON p1.payment_date = p2.payment_date + INTERVAL '1 month'
JOIN customer c
ON p1.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

This does execute data, but not what I desire.

What have I done wrong?

[CONTEXT](https://pastebin.com/VXSC8g3u)

Comment: Instead of `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p1.payment_date) = 2006`, you will get **MUCH** better performance with `p1.payment_date >= '2006-01-01' and p1.payment_date < '2007-01-01'`, which is _sargable_. Also, the `CONCAT() IN (subquery)` predicate is not helping you.

Comment: My 2 cents are: you should do your joins, and then filter out data in your ```WHERE``` clause, you're use of the payment table 3 times looks incorrect as well as the use of the customer table 2x.

Comment: Please put all & only what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Per the documentation. PS "cut & paste & runnable code including ..."

Answer (score -1):

There's not enough information here to solve this issue, but at a guess the problem is here:

```
AND p1.payment_date = p2.payment_date + INTERVAL '1 month'
```

Charges tend to be relatively clean, typically generated at certain times of the month to be due on specific days. But payments tend to be **MESSY**, and people are much less likely than you'd think to consistently pay on exactly the same day each month. But this conditional expression only matches payments that are **exactly** one month later. If this field is storing time components we're talking down to the microsecond.

This needs to allow the next month's payment to occur within some allowed range, or otherwise map to a charge or invoice that is known to match the desired month.